# check mail address whether is under gmail client <Ruby>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, email-client

Gmail able to let users to create whatever email style such as
account1@gmail.com
account2@company.com
account3@university.com

and many more.
currently, I'm using this contacts gem which is from https://github.com/liangzan/contacts ,
but when I login using account like account2@company.com..it cannot get my contacts since the email address not @gmail or @googlemail as I read the code.

So,how do I check the email address whether is under gmail address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check their MX records to see if they are hosted by a googlemail server.

This method will return true if it finds a googlemail server in the domain's mx records.
It uses google's dns server (8.8.8.8)

```
require 'resolv'

def isGmailAddress?(address)
  domain = address.split("@").last
  Resolv::DNS.open({:nameserver=>["8.8.8.8"]}) do |r|
    mx = r.getresources(domain,Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::MX)
    if mx.any? {|server| server.exchange.to_s.include? "googlemail" or server.exchange.to_s.include? "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"} then
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end

p isGmailAddress?("emailaddress@gmail.com")
```

look at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html

Comment: resolv cannot be required in the rails console?

Comment: yes it can, maybe you don't have the library?

Comment: hmm...thanks! it just preload inside...

Comment: did the method work for you?

Comment: emrm, nope...it return false for my gmail address "nichthinkof30@gmail.com" ,as well my hotmail

Comment: ohhh, sorry I thought you were scanning domains for some reason, let me refactor the code